# Trouble solving for voltage gain

Tags: mosfet, circuit-analysis

I've trying to determine the voltage gain of this circuit (a small signal model of a MOSFET and a few resistors), but I'm having trouble getting enough equations to substitute.
I see that ro and Rs are a voltage divider, so ...
$$V_{in} = V_1 + (V_{out} + g_m*V_1*r_o)\frac{R_s}{R_s + r_o}$$

$$\longrightarrow V_{out} = \frac{V_{in} - V_1(1 + gm*r_o\frac{R_s}{R_s + r_o})}{\frac{R_s}{R_s + r_o}}$$

But from here, I need V1 in terms of vin or vice versa and i'm not sure how to go about that. I'm also interested if somebody has a more "clever" solution to determine vout/vin.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMgjDs.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

For the curious, this is how I got to this schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIwGpN.png)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the history of comments the original schematic was updated.

---

Rs and Rd are now in series because we're in small signal mode so that ground symbol doesn't matter. Then Rs+Rd is || to ro. Should be super simple from there.

$$Vout-V_{1-} = -gmV_1*(Rs+Rd||ro)  $$
$$\frac{Vout-V_{1-}}{ro} = I_{ro}  $$
$$gmV1 + I_{ro} = I_{Rs} $$ 
$$ I_{Rs}*Rs = V_{1-}  $$

Should be enough to solve it?

Comment: I did a source conversion (that's why the equation for voltage is multiplied by ro). If I had used the original current source, ro would be in parallel with the source and the current would be gmV1.

Comment: @DanielB. Why's it being in parallel a problem though?

Comment: Because I thought it would be easier to solve this way; here I only have a single current loop rather than two.

Comment: @DanielB. Could you drop a schematic of the original circuit to make sure nothing went awry in your conversion?

Comment: I always get hung up on ground being in a static location ... that helps, thank you.

Comment: @DanielB. Yeah, that's pretty common. (Bad pun I didn't mean to happen.) As long as there's not another ground symbol or Vdd or Vcc or some other related assumed infinite source or sink of current, then a ground symbol is nothing more than a reference voltage. Glad I could finally help.

Comment: I just snorted laughing :D

Comment: @DanielB. Also, thinking a bit more on it, if you did the current source to voltage source conversion correctly, the same thing applies to your converted case. You have 3 resistors in series, collapse them into one and find the current. I'd just never seen that sort of conversion on a small signal model so I'm not sure if it was done right.

Comment: It was. A current source in parallel with a resistor can be transformed to a voltage source in series with the resistor, and the voltage is the current times the resistance.

Answer (score 0):

This is how we were taught to solve these problems in my classes:
[image: photo]